# Query related to Hadoop's Multiple node on same machine using VM

Tags: hadoop

I am little bit new to hadoop. I have implemented some task in hadoop. Until Now I am running it in Single Node Cluster. I am thinking to divert towards Multiple node cluster.

If I configured multiple node on same System using 2 Virtual Machine (Installing Ubuntu in both the VM), then the performance may increase or it will remain same as it is running on same machine.

(I think if I will run multiple node on same machine then time require to execute will be same or may be longer because all process will be in queue for execution as they will run on same machine. Am I thinking is right. If I am wrong pls correct as I have very little idea about this)

Please let me know asap. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance almost certainly for the following reasonsL:
1) You will have less memory available for the tasks, since VMs have theier overhead 
 
2) Networking will be slower between VMs then within the same OS.
 
3) Some disk IO overhead will be introduced by the VMs (although it is relatively small).
 
4) As far as I know per job overhead is related to the cluster size , so probabbly 1 node. Mbr> 
 cluster will have faster job start time then 2-node cluster.

I also do not see reasons why such cluster will perform better.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact configuration but most likely the performance would be slower.
Unless you also added more memory, more CPU and more IO when you added the new VM then the two VMs will compete for the same resources ...